# Is there an image carousel that is compatible with the Angular Jquery Mobile adapter?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, cordova, adapter, carousel

I've been working on a photo app and chose to build around the tigbro Angular-JQMobile adapter.  I've now come along to the point where I need an image carousel, and none of the options I am finding out and about are working for me.  I have tried [SwipeView](http://cubiq.org/swipeview) and the [Angular-Carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel)... no luck whatsoever.  I am locked in to some pretty old versions of Angular (1.0.6) and JQueryMobile (1.3.1).

Does anyone know an image carousel solution that could work in this environment?

(Added bonus, this is also happening within a Cordova project...)

Thanks.

Comment: Note:  Just tried PhotoSwipe, and got almost all the way to victory.  But not really.  After updating deprecated .live() methods, I got the gallery to appear, but the swipe action is broken.  The angular-JQM adapter reports: "Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined"

Comment: Also noted that Angular UI-Bootstrap has a carousel, but it requires Angular 1.0.8 minimum... the search continues.